# Mapping data flow SQL query and Parameters failing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-factory

In my mapping dataflow I have simplified this down to dimdate just for the test

**My parameters are**
[image]

The source even tells you exactly how to enter the select query if you are using parameters which is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Then I import but get two different errors
for parameterizing a table`

```
SELECT * FROM {$df_TableName}
```

I get

> This error from a select * or invidiual columns

[image]

I've tried just the WHERE clause (what I actually need) as a parameter but keep getting datatype mismatch errors

I then started testing multiple ways and it only allows the schema to be parameterised from my queries below

all of these other options seem to fail no matter what I do

```
SELECT * FROM [{$df_Schema}].[{$df_TableName}] Where [Period] = {$df_incomingPeriod}

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DimDate] Where [Period] = {$df_incomingPeriod}

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[{$df_TableName}] Where [Period] = {$df_incomingPeriod}

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DimDate] Where [Period] = 2106
```

[image]

I know there's an issue with the Integer datatype but don't know how to pass this to the query within the  parameter without changing its type as the sql engine cannot run [period] as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **CONCAT** function in expression builder to build the Query in Dataflow.

```
concat(<this> : string, <that> : string, ...) => string
```

> Note: Concatenates a variable number of strings together. All the variables should be in form of strings.

**Example 1**:

[image]

```
concat(toString("select * from "), toString($df_tablename))
```

[image]

**Example 2**:

```
concat(toString("select * from "), toString($df_tablename), ' ', toString(" where incomingperiod = "), toString($df_incomingPeriod))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Absolutely spot on! I wish there was a way of doing some better debugging in mapping dataflows so I could better understand the failures. I guess it takes some experience

Comment: This does not work as I am getting the "Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions" error because concat is a column operand. Even when I place the entire query in the parameter and just use the parameter it is the same error. This is my query: concat(toString("select * from PharmacyMaster"),' ', toString(" where NationalProviderIdentifier in "), toString($parameter1))

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, it worked like magic for me. I was struggling with parameterizing tables= names which I was passing through Array list.
Created a data flow parameter and gave this value:
@item().TABLE_NAME